# Use Master-Slave architecture in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, architecture, codeigniter-3

In order to use Master-slave architecture (As known as read-write DB replication) in code-igniter 3, I need to check every SQL query and redirect it to a slave (read) database if the query is a read type query. Checking the query is not the problem, Redirecting it is.

CodeIgniter 3 already has a function to check the query.
I edited the function where all queries pass by to close the connection, select a database and establish the connection, but it does not work properly, it just throws a generic SQL error without any error code or text.

**system/database/DB_driver.php**

```
/**
 * Execute the query
 *
 * @param   string  $sql    an SQL query
 * @return  mixed
 */
protected function _execute($sql)
{
    if (!$this->is_write_type($sql)) {
            $this->_close();
            $this->db_select('slave');
            $this->db_connect();
    }
    return $this->conn_id->query($this->_prep_query($sql));
}
```

This approach results in the following error on any read query.

[image: Translate: An error occurred on database]

Translate: An error occurred on database

**Finally: What am I doing wrong? Which approach should I use?**

EDIT: There is no futher information about the error except it is coming from the following line on a model file:

```
class Estabelecimentospagamentosmodel extends CI_Model
{
//some code above
        $query = $this->db->get();
//Some code below
}
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error? What do the web server logs say? Which MySQL version?